# nginx / php5-fpm 502

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Есть: nginx и настроенный php5-fpm, которые успешно себе проработали несколько месяцев, но вот сегодня днем появилась 502 ошибка. Собсно, проблема по логам проблема стандартная - отвалился php5-fpm.

**/var/log/nginx/error.log:**

```
2015/10/14 10:33:14 [error] 2122#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:35:55 [error] 2122#0: *6 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:36:24 [error] 2122#0: *6 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:36:30 [error] 2122#0: *6 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:41:48 [error] 2122#0: *13 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:42:08 [error] 2122#0: *13 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
2015/10/14 10:42:17 [error] 2122#0: *13 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
```

Ага. Ну смотрим php-fpm...
**/var/log/php5-fpm.log**:

```
[11-Oct-2015 07:39:48] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[14-Oct-2015 10:01:43] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[14-Oct-2015 10:12:44] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[14-Oct-2015 10:20:20] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[14-Oct-2015 10:26:50] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[14-Oct-2015 10:28:09] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Странно. Всё перезапускаем - не помогло. Сверяем сокет, по которому nginx подключается к php5-fpm - всё нормально.
Смотрим [phpinfo](http://akirocs.com/info.php) в корне сайта - работает...
Смотрим localhost - получаем стандартный index.html с кодом 200(ОК).
Смотрим [сайт](http://akirocs.com) - ошибка 502.

Вывод: php работает, nginx работает, phpinfo успешно отчитывается о успешной работе... но при заходе на сайт получаем 502 и запись в лог по типу

```
2015/10/14 10:33:14 [error] 2122#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 88.156.134.5, server: akirocs.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "akirocs.com"
```

Вопрос. Какого черта при заходе на сайт php-fpm не работает, но при этом phpinfo в корне этого сайта отлично работает? Реверты коммитов на утреннюю версию сайта(когда всё ещё работало) не помогли.

Чуть ниже прилагаю **akirocs.conf**:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 128M;
        root /home/akirocs/akirocs-web/web;
        index index.php;

        server_name akirocs.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Открыл сайт, ошибок нет, все отображается.

Comment: о_о не может быть

Comment: @Visman, спасибо. почистил куки, теперь всё ок. значит таки код тупит, а не nginx/php. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Ситуация тривиальная, но может кому-то поможет это сообщение. Nginx обрывал подключение по локальному сокету после 10 секунд, регистрируя тайм-аут сокета в логах. В силу "локальности" время таймаута по локальному unix-сокету обычно составляет около 10 секунд, а не 30 как обычно. В одном из последних коммитов был найден код с непрямой рекурсией, в результате php зависал до момента выброса ошибки StackOverflow, но ошибка эта падает через 20-30 секунд после вызова скрипта.
Получается, что nginx не получил ответа за 10 секунд, и оборвал соединение, попутно сообщая всем что php-fpm не отвечает, хотя на самом деле php-fpm просто упал в рекурсию.

Comment: в таком случае nginx вернул бы 504